# Facebook Android - Install App and Engage App campaigns are not delivering deferred link

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-ads-api

I have done everything in my app to fetch deferred links for ads, but they never deliver the deferred link. AppLinkData is always null:

```
private class DeferredAppLinkDataCompletionHandlerListener implements AppLinkData.CompletionHandler {

    @Override
    public void onDeferredAppLinkDataFetched(AppLinkData appLinkData) {

        if (appLinkData != null) {

            final Uri deferredReceivedUri = appLinkData.getTargetUri();

        } else {
            // Always null
        }
    }
}
```

I have even tested the deferred link fetching, using the Ads Helper of this link: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/app-ads-helper/?id=1460634867586845 and everything work:

[image]

... but they don't with a real ad.

What else should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known issue and it is being tracked here https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/393947180805373.

You can subscribe to that bug to follow the updates.